# Hyperlink in Dynamics CRM 4.0 Notes

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-4, crm

Is it possible to have a clickable hyperlink in the notes section of a CRM entity?

This is the notes control that resides in `_controls/notes/notesdata.aspx.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

not by default, you could alter the _controls/notes/notesdata.aspx page to include this functionality but it would be an unsupported customisation.